# Custom font with dynamic type in interface builder

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

I have several views in my Storyboard which have `UILabel`s. These labels are set to `Automatically Adjusts Font` and use text styles like `Body` or `Headline`.

I know there is a programmatic approach as such:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-custom-font-with-dynamic-type/

```
let label = UILabel()
label.font = scaledFont.font(forTextStyle: textStyle)
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

However, given that I have already laid out my labels and set their text styles, is there a way to use a custom font **AND** text styles from within interface builder? Or maybe somehow override their font-family while respecting the text style already set on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd need to use the programmatic approach. However, it is easy to write a little loop that runs through all your labels and for each one, fetches the dynamic type "role" already set in interface builder and substitutes a UIFontMetrics value based on that "role" and the desired custom font.